# How to include additional database columns in list?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I am working with Mimir's Android tutorial #10 concerning displaying data from a pre-populated database in a list. In their database, they have four columns, namely: (1) ingredient_description, (2) in_stock, (3) _id, and (4) ingredient_name. However, in their list, they only display data from the ingredient_name column. For example, their list looks like this...

---

Ice

---

Water

---

Etc.

---

But what I am trying to do is display data from ALL four columns in a row, like so...

---

Ice
Description: Frozen water
ID: 1
In stock: yes

---

Water
Description: H2O
ID: 2
In stock: yes

---

Etc.

---

The tutorial uses bindView and newView, and according to their comments, "This makes our code a bit cleaner, and is the better way to do this."

I have spent a lot of time researching this issue and I haven't been able to figure out how to get these three additional columns from the database to display in the row. The following is the original code along with some changes I made (my changes are noted in the comments with * * *).

I know I am still missing something, but that's where I'm stuck. Could someone please advise what is missing in order to display the data from these three additional columns? If possible, please let me know *specifically* what is missing / how to fix rather than pointing me to tutorials (I have already looked at so many and, unfortunately, nothing has been able to answer my question). Please also keep in mind that the sample code uses bindView and newView so it needs to work with that. Thanks much for any help.

```
package com.mimirsoft.tutorial10; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.util.Locale; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.database.SQLException; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder; 
import android.util.Log; 
class IngredientHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
//we declare a bunch of useful constants 
//the should be pretty obvious what they are! 
private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.mimirsoft.tutorial10/databases/"; 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="ingredients.db"; 
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1; 
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Ingredients"; 
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id"; 
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "ingredient_name"; 

//* * * MY ADD * * * 
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE2 = "ingredient_description";

//* * * MY ADD * * * 
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE3 = "in_stock";


public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite; 
private final Context myContext; 
public IngredientHelper(Context context) { 
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION); 
this.myContext = context; 
// check if exists and copy database from resource 
//createDB(); 
} 
@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
// check if exists and copy database from resource 
} 
@Override 
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
} 
public void createDatabase() { 
createDB(); 
} 
private void createDB() { 
boolean dbExist = DBExists(); 
if (!dbExist) { 
//By calling this method we create an empty database into the default system location 
//We need this so we can overwrite that database with our database. 
this.getReadableDatabase(); 
//now we copy the database we included! 
copyDBFromResource(); 
} 
} 
private boolean DBExists() { 
SQLiteDatabase db = null; 
try { 
String databasePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME; 
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); 
db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault()); 
db.setLockingEnabled(true); 
db.setVersion(1); 
} catch (SQLiteException e) { 
Log.e("SqlHelper", "database not found"); 
} 
if (db != null) { 
db.close(); 
} 
return db != null ? true : false; 
} 
private void copyDBFromResource() { 
InputStream inputStream = null; 
OutputStream outStream = null; 
String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME; 
try { 
inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME); 
outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
int length; 
while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) { 
outStream.write(buffer, 0, length); 
} 
outStream.flush(); 
outStream.close(); 
inputStream.close(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file."); 
} 
} 
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException { 
String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME; 
dbSqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); 
} 
@Override 
public synchronized void close() { 
if (dbSqlite != null) 
{ 
dbSqlite.close(); 
} 
super.close(); 
} 
public Cursor getCursor() { 
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder(); 
queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME); 

// * * * MY CHANGE - CHANGED FROM... * * * 
//String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE}; 
//* * * TO... * * * 
//String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_TITLE2, COLUMN_TITLE3}; 

//make sure you get your search by string pass correctly! 
Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null, 
null, null, null, "ingredient_name ASC"); 
return mCursor; 
} 
public String getName(Cursor c) { 
return(c.getString(1)); 
} 
}
```

And...

```
package com.mimirsoft.tutorial10; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.CursorAdapter; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
//This tutorial introduces the CursorAdaptor, explains how it is different 
//from the Array Adapter, and also introduces the database functionality. 
//We will build a ListView from a Database of cocktail Ingredients 
public class Tutorial10 extends Activity { 
private IngredientHelper dbIngredientHelper = null; 
private Cursor ourCursor = null; 
private IngredientAdapter adapter=null; 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
try 
{ 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main); 
//this is our ListView element, obtained by id from our XML layout 
ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView); 
//create our database Helper 
dbIngredientHelper=new IngredientHelper(this); 
//we call the create right after initializing the helper, just in case 
//they have never run the app before 
dbIngredientHelper.createDatabase(); 
// 
//open the database!! Our helper now has a SQLiteDatabase database object 
dbIngredientHelper.openDataBase(); 
//get our cursor. A cursor is a pointer to a dataset, in this case 
//a set of results from a database query 
ourCursor=dbIngredientHelper.getCursor(); 
//tell android to start managing the cursor, 
//we do this just incase our activity is interrupted or ends, we want the activity 
//to close and deactivate the cursor, as needed 
startManagingCursor(ourCursor); 
//create our adapter 
adapter=new IngredientAdapter(ourCursor); 
//set the adapter!!! 
myListView.setAdapter(adapter); 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ 
// this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the log 
Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString()); 
// this is the line that prints out the location in 
// the code where the error occurred. 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
} 
class IngredientAdapter extends CursorAdapter { 
IngredientAdapter(Cursor c) { 
super(Tutorial10.this, c); 
} 
@Override 
//this is a CusorAdapter 
//instead of Using a getView and if(row==null) 
// we use bindView and newView calls 
//we can get away with this because CursorAdapters have 
//a default implementation of getView that calls bindView and newView 
//as needed. This makes our code a bit cleaner, and is the better way to 
//do this. 
public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, 
Cursor c) { 
IngredientHolder holder=(IngredientHolder)row.getTag(); 
holder.populateFrom(c, dbIngredientHelper); 
} 
@Override 
public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, 
ViewGroup parent) { 
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater(); 
View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false); 
IngredientHolder holder=new IngredientHolder(row); 
row.setTag(holder); 
return(row); 
} 
} 
static class IngredientHolder { 
private TextView name=null; 
IngredientHolder(View row) { 
name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ingredientText); 
} 
void populateFrom(Cursor c, IngredientHelper r) { 
name.setText(r.getName(c)); 
} 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, you could just add a line break at the end of each line in your string. That would break the string where you want. The negative to doing it that way is that you would not be able to style each line separately.

A better way to do it would be to create a layout and add each string as a text view. There is an example in the Android API Demos under, Views/Lists/4. ListAdapter. So add that to your device or run it on the emulator. 
And the package name is com.example.android.apis.view, the class is List4.java.

Here's the subclass from the API example.

```
/**
 * We will use a SpeechView to display each speech. It's just a LinearLayout
 * with two text fields.
 *
 */
private class SpeechView extends LinearLayout {
    public SpeechView(Context context, String title, String words) {
        super(context);

        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        // Here we build the child views in code. They could also have
        // been specified in an XML file.

        mTitle = new TextView(context);
        mTitle.setText(title);
        addView(mTitle, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mDialogue = new TextView(context);
        mDialogue.setText(words);
        addView(mDialogue, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure though how I get the three additional columns from the database to appear in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something similar to this. Pass the cursor and select which column you want with an integer and save the data to your variables.

private void getName(c){

```
 name.setText(c.getString(0)
 name2.setText(c.getString(1)
 name3.setText(c.getString(2)
 name4.setText(c.getString(3)
```

}

Then just add to more text views to your layout and set their text with your string from the db.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please clarify where to put this code. Also, do I still leave public String getName(Cursor c) {        return(c.getString(1));     } as is or does that also need to be modified? Can you also clarify how this works in conjunction with bindView/getTag and newView/setTag in the above sample code? I guess I just don't see how it will pick up the additional database columns to display. Sorry for my ignorance...I am trying to wrap my mind around this whole thing, but it's just not clicking for me. Thanks for any help.